# How do I access/change pixels in a javascript image object?

Tags: javascript, image-processing

I'm drawing an image to a canvas for display on a web page.  I have two copies of the image.  The first is the original or ground-truth and the second is a copy that will have various image processing algorithms applied to it.

How can I copy the pixels from the ground-truth image to the copy and how can I access the pixels in the copy to process the image once I've copied it?

[Examples I've seen](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1CHFX_en-GBGB455GB455&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=javascript%20image%20object%20pixel%20manipulation) so far all involve accessing and manipulating a canvas object rather than image data.   Is this the recommended solution?  Draw the original image to a canvas and then process the canvas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the image data use getImageData() method of the canvas context and then access the pixel data from the data property. Each pixel in the data property contains the red, green, blue and alpha channel. So if you did draw your image on to the canvas you could then do

```
var imageData = context.getImageData(imageX, imageY, imageWidth, imageHeight);
var data = imageData.data;
```

Then you could pick out specific pixel data from x and y coordinates like so

```
// pick out pixel data from x, y coordinate
var x = 20;
var y = 20;
var red = data[((imageWidth * y) + x) * 4];
var green = data[((imageWidth * y) + x) * 4 + 1];
var blue = data[((imageWidth * y) + x) * 4 + 2];
var alpha = data[((imageWidth * y) + x) * 4 + 3];
```

You can find more information on how to work with image data using canvas right [here](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-get-image-data-tutorial/).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Is this is only way David?  I have to use a canvas?

Comment: This is the easiest way i can think of. You could as well use the FileReader  API to to create an ArrayBuffer of the image file using the readAsArrayBuffer method which will read a Blob or File and produce a fixed length binary data buffer. But than you would have to build your own function to extract the pixel data out of the buffer. The canvas method does this for you.

Comment: I don't want to go that far, no.  So second canvas buffer it is.

Comment: I had some fun with this to see if I could use it to tint an image with alpha. Worked out great in the end: https://botched-deployments.com/posts/messing-with-images.

Basically looping through pixels and doing per-pixel manipulations based on the RGBA values