# tensorflow js RGB to Lab from input img

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I have been searching and debugging but I can not find anything that works for me. I'm doing a web application in which I try to go from black and white images to color and for that I have put an input in which I load the image and make the inference (currently with an image-to-image model).

The fact is that I want to transform the image of rgb to lab as a preprocess before it enters the network because that is how I intend to train it. My code is as follows:

```
var myInput = document.getElementById('myFileInput');

function processPic() {
    if (myInput.files && myInput.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#prev_img_id').attr('src', e.target.result);
            //Initiate the JavaScript Image object.
            var image = new Image();
           //Set the Base64 string return from FileReader as source.
           image.src = e.target.result;
           image.onload = function () {
               //alert(this.height)
               const webcamImage = tf.fromPixels(this);
               const batchedImage = webcamImage.expandDims(0);
               predict(batchedImage.toFloat().div(tf.scalar(127)).sub(tf.scalar(1)))
            }
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(myInput.files[0]);
    }
}

myInput.addEventListener('change', processPic, false);


function predict(the_img) {
    //get predictions 
    let pred = mobilenet.predict(the_img);
    //retreive the highest probability class label 
    let cls = pred.argMax().buffer().values[0];

    alert(IMAGENET_CLASSES[cls]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a some code to do this using the tensorflow.js operations the code can be optimized further with matrix multiplications but it will work and should put you on the right path if this is still relevant.

[RGB2LAB TFJS](https://gist.github.com/aribornstein/5c0509ed2153c546c3d2a945eded21de)

Answer (score 1):

There are some resources around regarding the conversion RGB to LAB e.g. http://www.easyrgb.com/en/math.php.

You could also give this JS implementation a try (https://github.com/antimatter15/rgb-lab, which is actually using the equations from the *easyrgb* website), calling the `rgb2lab()` function inside your `image.onload`.

To access the image data required by ``, you can have a look at this SO thread ([How do I access/change pixels in a javascript image object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30453726/how-do-i-access-change-pixels-in-a-javascript-image-object)) i.e. using an intermediary canvas.